# Android Camera.autoFocus and FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE

Tags: android, camera, autofocus

I have a camera app that allows the user to take pictures.  On my main screen I have a camera rendered on a SurfaceView.  When the user takes a photo, I call camera.autoFocus and on the AutoFocusCallback callback I call camera.takePicture.  Then I save the photo and go to another activity to preview the photo.  I call camera.stopPreview() when leaving the camera page (onPause), and camera.startPreview() when coming back (onResume).

The camera is initialized using FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE.  I do not recycle the camera when coming back to the camera page (since it is a slow operation that takes ~2 seconds), but just call startPreview if the camera has been initialized before.

Here is my problem.  Before taking the first photo, continuous autofocus works fine since FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE is set up initially on the camera.  However after calling camera.autoFocus, FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE stops working.  Later when I return to the same screen and call startPreview, continuous auto focus does not work kick in anymore.

Is there a way to restart continuous autofocus without having to restart the camera?  I'd like to avoid restarting the camera as this causes several seconds of delay for the user.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed the issue by calling camera.cancelAutoFocus().  This caused continuous autofocus to kick in again.

Comment: If applications want to resume the continuous focus, cancelAutoFocus must be called. Restarting the preview will not resume the continuous autofocus.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE