# Android focus and exposure stops working with FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, autofocus

I'm making a small camera app, and I'm having a little problem with capturing several pictures.

First I found that after every **mCamera.takePicture()** we need to call **mCamera.startPreview()** on **onPictureTaken()** callback to keep seeing the preview after the first shot.

So, after this discovery, I've added a code to set the camera focus mode to **FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE** in initialization, because it was not getting focus automatically.

What happens is that Auto Exposure and Auto Focus stop to work after the first shot.

I found that the Auto Exposure and Auto Focus works for a brief time after the shots and blocks.

Is there any function I need to call to restart this features after a shot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378375/1396264) will probably work for you:

> I fixed the issue by calling `camera.cancelAutoFocus()`. This caused continuous autofocus to kick in again.

After you take the shot, call [`camera.cancelAutoFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#cancelAutoFocus())